# Delete the lines of a word document till a string in C#

Tags: c#, string

I was trying a case where i need to find a string and delete all the lines till the string is found.
E.g. I have a doc like
ABC..
DEF..
index
LKV
MNP
So, i wanted to delete every line till the word index is found including index and remain line remains.

I have tried following code but it does not look working and throwing some exception.

```
    if (this.Doc_path.Text != "")
        {
            string Doc_pth = this.Doc_path.Text;
            string Serch_String1 = "Appendix";
            Word.Application app = new Word.Application();
            app.Visible = true;
            app.WindowState = Word.WdWindowState.wdWindowStateNormal;

            Word.Document docOpen = app.Documents.Open(Doc_pth);
            Object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            docOpen.Content.Find.ClearFormatting();
            try
            {
                var range = docOpen.Content;
                foreach (var para in range.Paragraphs)
                {
                    //if (.Find.Execute(Serch_String1))
                    //if (range.Find.Execute(Serch_String1))
                    if(para.ToString().Contains(Serch_String1))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("found");
                        break;
                        
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //range.Expand(Word.WdUnits.wdParagraph); // or change to .wdSentence or .wdParagraph
                        ///range.Expand(Word.WdUnits.wdParagraph); // or change to .wdSentence or .wdParagraph
                        range.Delete(para);
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            catch(Exception exe)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exe.ToString());
                throw;
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Done!");
            docOpen.Close(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
            app.Quit(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

            //mp.Close();

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter valid path for document");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exceptions does it throw? Be detailed.

Comment: @Amit Welcome to StackOverflow!  If you have an example of one (or more) of the exceptions that are thrown, please either edit your post with those exceptions or include them in comments.  That will help the community to resolve your issue faster.

Answer (score 1):

The following process, probably, be helpful for deleting the text from the line up to string is found.

I am taking the string as an example you provided.

```
//let the original text
string strDel = "ABC.. DEF.. index LKV MNP";

//the word to upto delete the text
string delTillWord = "index";

//length of the word upto delete
int delUpto = delTillWord.Length;

//first remove the string upto first letter of upto deleting word
string strAfterDel = strDel.Remove(0, (strDel.Length - strDel.IndexOf(delTillWord)));

//then delete remaining word by taking its length
strAfterDel = strAfterDel.Remove(0, delUpto);
```

In the variable `strAfterDel`, the remaining string is `"LKV MNP"`.

**Another way** is to create a separate method and call it:

```
public static string GetAfterDelete(string strDel, string delTillWord)
{
    //length of the word upto delete
    int delUpto = delTillWord.Length;

    //first remove the string upto first letter of upto deleting word
    string strAfterDel = strDel.Remove(0, (strDel.Length - strDel.IndexOf(delTillWord)));

    //then delete remaining word by taking its length
    strAfterDel = strAfterDel.Remove(0, delUpto);

    return strAfterDel;
}
```

Use the above method as:

```
string strDel = "ABC.. DEF.. index LKV MNP";
string strAfterDel = GetAfterDelete(strDel, "index");
```

Comment: nice you beat me to it

Comment: Purpose is not to beat anyone :)  Then you have to upvote it for a nice gesture and its is SO culture as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Using contains will only return a boolean. You could use indexOf() combined with string.remove().

Not sure about the context of your `para` object so you may not need the toString().

but to get the index position of the term/character you could do:
`int position = para.indexOf('term');`
then remove the text prior to the term using:
`string result = para.Remove(0, position);`
where the two parameters are start and end position.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I am doing these operations on  a document. where i need to search for a string in the document which is at a location pages down and needs to delete everything prior to it including the searched string.